# Adding a node to hadoop cluster without restarting master

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

i have created a hadoop cluster and wanted to add a new node node in the cluster running as a slave without restarting the master node

how can this be acheived

Answer (score 0):

Datanodes and nodemanagers can be added without restarting the namenode(s) or resource manager(s).

More specifically, these need to be ran on the machines of those *running* services

Namenode

```
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes
```

ResourceManager

```
rmadmin -refreshNodes
```